# Let's punch a hole in this tag and let [rsync]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, burninate-request

I can't think of any justification for [rsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rsync) as a tag on a programming site. It's not like we have an [ls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ls) or [scp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scp) tag.

Comment: There are criteria to be checked if a tag merits deletion: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191 please read them and update your question with your findings.

Comment: Not that we necessarily *should* have them, but [tag:scp] and [tag:ls] *do* exist.

Comment: Rsync also happens to be a network protocol (partial/delta transfers), and has a few basic implementations in some programming languages.

Comment: Is it _causing a problem_ by being here?

Comment: @JoshCaswell - it seems to attract people who don't know how to use rsync as such, causing OT posts.

Comment: Misuse of a tag is not enough to justify burninating it. A tag cleanup might be necessary, but [rsync] is a useful tag to have around.

Comment: @pizzastaticvoidmain actually, it is. That's what got [internet] removed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Writing as an answer as it's my view and it may become longer than a comment.

I think [rsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rsync) has valid use within programming, as it can be induced programmatically.  The difference between [ls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ls) and [rsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rsync) within the coding realm is that [ls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ls) is simply list. When a programmer wants to ask a question about lists, they'll ask something like **How do I list using XYZ?**.

It's much more generic than [rsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rsync). A *potentially good* question may revolve around the premise of invoking rsync in bash.

For that, I think it's a valid tag - just used out of place too often. Despite the tag's very clear description about how it should be used, it's still getting used in a way that's not desirable.

I'm not sure what flags are available, but maybe something to flag a tooltip if [rsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rsync) tag is added about proper use to remind the user on proper use.

Answer (score 14):

I'd recommend keeping it and dealing with questions individually. Rsync is a commonly used tool that introduces *many* subtle complexities for automation, which usually involve kind-of-advanced scripting, which tends to fall into on-topic.

Additionally there are plenty of libraries around invoking rsync (either as a linked object wrapped in another language, or through shell execution) that it's worth treating it case-by-case instead of in a blanket way.

I can think of plenty of *off* topic examples, but the on-topic ones I can think of from my own adventures using it alone tell me that we should keep it.

I think I've yelled at [rsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rsync) more than [sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sed), to be honest, but that's purely anecdotal.